# How to apply displacement mapping with tessellation?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpu, shader, tessellation

I'm feeling like I'm grasping at straws right now researching this!

My goal is to write a simple water shader. The plan is to use tessellation to implement dynamic LODs, and apply a height map based on fractal noise (ref this [paper](http://www-evasion.inrialpes.fr/Membres/Fabrice.Neyret/images/fluids-nuages/waves/Jonathan/articlesCG/GPUBasedRealTimeSimulationAndRendering2005.pdf)). Where I am stumbling is where we are supposed to apply the height map. It seems like it should be applied to the vertex shader, but the vertex shader precedes the tessellation shaders.
**So I am looking to apply the displace vertices at the tessellation evaluation shader (OpenGL) using noise, is that the best way to go?**

For the noise, I am planning on inputting the vertices positions to the noise function.

It is confusing to me because so far I have not found any examples on the web on the matter. I am seeing people [people](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial30/tutorial30.html) sampling in the tessellation shader, but I don't have a texture, only noise. I've also seen someone mention something about using a geometry shader to displace vertices. What's the widely accepted procedure here?

I'm wondering about the impacts of the performances and advice on whether I should think of generating noise texture and interpolating those instead.

Comment: "*I don't have a texture, only noise*" Then sample the noise. A texture is just a (discrete) function that maps values to other values. Just like a noise function, right?

Comment: @NicolBolas My interpretation of a texture is literally an image file or some sort, that is passed as a sampler2d. I think that matches your definition, right? So I could pass an image of a noise, but I want the water to be animating with time. So my idea was to use the noise() function in the gpu directly. Is this considered "sampling the noise"?